# No qualifying bean of type [HrEmployeesReportOutput] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

I have the error below when trying to run a springboot application , I am not able to inject the HrEmployeesReportOutput class by using the @Autowired annotation, I tried other ways, but didnt work.

would you please help me with this?

```
No qualifying bean of type [com.nearshoretechnology.focalpoint.interactors.hremployees.HrEmployeesReportOutput] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/management/hr/employees/report")
public class HrManagerEmployeeReportController {

    @Autowired
    private HrEmployeesReportOutput hrEmployeesReportPresenter;

    private HrEmployeesReportInput hrReportEmployees;

    @Secured({ HR_ADMIN, BENCH_ADMIN })
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model) {
        HrEmployeesReportForm form = new HrEmployeesReportForm();
        String username = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
        form.setUsername(username);

        this.hrReportEmployees.setReportEmployeesPresenter(hrEmployeesReportPresenter);

        model.addAllAttributes(hrReportEmployees.employeeReport(form));

        return "management/hr/reports/employees";
    }

}
```

```
public interface HrEmployeesReportOutput extends InteractorOutput<HrEmployeesReportResult> {

}
```

```
public interface InteractorOutput<T> {

  Map<String, Object> generateViewModel(T result);
}
```

```
public class HrEmployeesReportResult extends BaseResult {}
```

```
public class BaseResult {}
```

```
public interface HrEmployeesReportInput {


    Map<String, Object> employeeReport(HrEmployeesReportForm form);

    void setReportEmployeesPresenter(HrEmployeesReportOutput presenter);



}
```

Comment: Use @Component in HrEmployeesReportOutput class.

Comment: @DebadattaMishra
I added the Component annotation, but still the same

Comment: @DebadattaMishra

Comment: @DebadattaMishra

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.nearshoretechnology.focalpoint.interactors.hremployees.HrEmployeesReportOutput] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: HrEmployeesReportOutput is an interface, you need to add that to the class implementing the interface.

Comment: You should have @ComponentScan, Configuration annotations properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have at least one class which implements your `HrEmployeesReportOutput` interface
And if you are using `@ComponentScan` (added automatically if you are using spring-boot) your class must have annotation `@Component`

For example:

`@Component
public class HrEmployeesReportOutputImpl implements HrEmployeesReportOutput{...}`

Comment: thanks, that gave me the idea and it solved the issue

Comment: there was another class involved that needed to implement what you mentioned :

@Component
public class HrEmployeesReportWebPresenter extends AbstractPresenter<HrEmployeesReportResult> implements HrEmployeesReportOutput {